# Make a typescript react prop optional depending upon array element values of another prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, optional-parameters

So, I have this react component that takes in certain string or array or strings, plus some other properties as props. Here's a simple definition of said component.

```
type Feature = "feature1" | "feature2" | "feature3";

export interface FeatureWrapperProps {
    feature: Feature | Feature[];
    requiredPropForFeature1: number;
    requiredPropForFeature2: () => void;
    requiredPropForFeature3: string;
}

const FeatureWrapper = ({
    feature,
    requiredPropForFeature1,
    requiredPropForFeature2,
    requiredPropForFeature3
}) => {
}
```

What I want to achieve is depending upon the feature or array of features passed in, I want to make some properties of FeatureWrapperProps optional. For example, if `features = 'feature1'` then I want the props to be

```
interface FeatureWrapperProps {
    feature: Feature | Feature[];
    requiredPropForFeature1: number; // required
    requiredPropForFeature2?: () => void; // optional as this is only required for feature 2 
    requiredPropForFeature3?: string;;// optional as this is only required for feature 3
}
```

and if `features = ['feature1', 'feature2']` then I want the props to be

```
interface FeatureWrapperProps {
    feature: Feature | Feature[];
    requiredPropForFeature1: number; // required
    requiredPropForFeature2: () => void; // required 
    requiredPropForFeature3?: string; // optional as this is only required for feature 3
}
```

I tried to make props optional by using generics and inferring the value of the generic like so

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type MakeOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [SubKey in K]?: Maybe<T[SubKey]> };

type RequiredProps<T extends PaidFeatureType> = T extends 'feature1'
    ? MakeOptional<FeatureWrapperProps, 'feature2' | 'feature3'>
    : T extends 'feature2'
    ? MakeOptional<
          FeatureWrapperProps,
          'feature1' | 'feature3'
      >
    : T extends 'feature3'
    ? MakeOptional<FeatureWrapperProps, 'feature1' | 'feature2'>
    : FeatureWrapperProps;


const FeatureWrapper = <T extends Feature>({
    feature,
    requiredPropForFeature1,
    requiredPropForFeature2,
    requiredPropForFeature3
}: RequiredProps<T>) => {
```

This works perfectly if I only pass in `feature` prop as a string but breaks if I pass `feature` prop as an array.
When I pass `feature` as an array like `feature={['feature1', 'feature2']}` then it makes all three props optional

How can I achieve this sort of type checking as I want to have this be done at compile time so the rest of the code won't be filled with `if {} else {}` runtime checks